# Layout issue for my android application

Tags: android

I am trying to design a layout in android. My problem is the squares namely (a,b,c,d,e,f) i will be able to make them equal in vertical direction one over the other using weights but how to scale the to the exact length in horizontal direction, as this will vary from device to device, i want each of them to be square?any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: post your xml file....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/header_gradient"
    android:paddingBottom="5dip"
    android:paddingTop="5dip" >

    <!-- Logo Start -->

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.01"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
        android:src="@drawable/your_logo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtlogout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/log_off_new" />

    <!-- Logo Ends -->
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/trips_layout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/trips"
                style="@style/DashboardButton"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/trip_icon"
                android:text="@string/icon_label_trips" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/locate_centres_layout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/locate_centres"
                style="@style/DashboardButton"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/locate_centre_icon"
                android:text="@string/icon_label_locate_centre" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/documentation_layout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/documentation"
                style="@style/DashboardButton"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/documentation_icon"
                android:text="@string/icon_label_documentation" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/mySchedule_layout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mySchedule"
                style="@style/DashboardButton"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/schedule_icon"
                android:text="@string/icon_label_my_schedule" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/Cust_Mgmt_layout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Cust_Mgmt"
                style="@style/DashboardButton"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/customer_icon"
                android:text="@string/icon_label_customer_management" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/settings_layout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/settings"
                style="@style/DashboardButton"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/settings_icon"
                android:text="@string/icon_label_settings" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Try this**

Implement and check

Comment: Hi Atish, thanks for your reply, but in this layout you are dividing the whole width in two parts what i am asking is for example the screen is 6 inch in height and 4 inch wide, if i will stack 6 boxes one over another each one will have height 1 inch and will take up the entire height. now the width of the stack should be also i inch so the width of 3 inches is left next to the pile of boxes

Comment: this can be achieved by adding a blank view and setting its weight equal to the sum of weights of the boxes